# MySQL INNER JOIN using an OR whilst logging in

Tags: php, mysql

My table structure is as follows:

```
~ MEMBERS ~
UID (a-i)
NAME
EMAIL

~ COUPLES ~
UID_1
UID_2
PASSWORD
SALT
```

When a couple sign up, their UIDs get inserted in to the couples table, along with their joint password (and its salt). Now, when logging in, I need to join the tables so I can check the password for either user.

*i.e. Find Email Address > See which Couple they are in > Check against Password*

This is my current query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM MEMBERS m 
INNER JOIN COUPLES c ON ((c.UID_1 = m.UID) OR (c.UID_2 = m.UID)) 
WHERE EMAIL = '$email'";
```

(I'm only using `*` for now as I can't figure out exactly what I need to select for the `INNER JOIN` to work.)

And the rest of the code on `login-script.php` is as follows:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    header('Location: index.php?msg=error4');
    exit();
}

$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $data['SALT'] . hash('sha256', $password));

if ($hash != $data['PASSWORD']) {
    header('Location: index.php?msg=error5');
    exit();
}
else {
    echo "Logged in.";
}
```

?>

If I try and log in, the error message `?msg=error5` gets thrown, which means that the passwords do not match, but I cannot see a problem in that part of my code. I believe it's telling me they do not match because it's not looking in the right table/for the right data, which must be something wrong with my `INNER JOIN`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

*EDIT: I realise now that it would have made a lot more sense to have just put the password and salt in to `MEMBERS` for both records so I'm only selecting from one table, but the deed is done and I'm curious to see if this is possible.*

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't have made more sense to put the password in the MEMBERS table. It's actually a good idea in terms of security to have username and password seperated.

Comment: Well, that's good to know then, thank you. I inadvertently did something correctly!

Comment: Not a good thing though for naughty couples who have multiple affairs, they may locked out of the system :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I tried your structure and code on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all and this works for me:

```
SELECT * from members M JOIN couples C ON uid_1=Uid or uid_2=uid
WHERE email='youremail';
```

Perhaps the problem is that in the table there is more than 1 couple a person is actually in?
Like:

```
uid_1, uid_2, pass
1       2     xxx
1       3     yyy
```

You should either limit it on database side to unique columns or change code, because if you don't, you might be getting more than 1 row as result and you would need to check every couple's password against particular UID.

Comment: Odd to know that it works on there, but not where I am. Let me try working the () out of the syntax in the query and try again. The registration form is set up so that each email address can only be used once, and `UID_1` and `UID_2` are pulled from `UID` which is auto-incrementing, so there's no way it can be duplicated.

Comment: He's using a `JOIN` too - not an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a MySQL `JOIN`? I thought they were INNER, LEFT, RIGHT and FULL?

Comment: @MatthewPeckham MySQL `JOIN` [defaults](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to `INNER JOIN` (although always better to write it explicitly)

Comment: @Gnudiff - Tried the code again, and still not logging in. Same error. I even double-checked the password in-case a typo on registration was causing all these problems!

Comment: Turns out my problem was actually with the password itself. On the registration script I had `$password = hash('sha256', $salt, $hash);` instead of `$password = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);` so they weren't matching! Thank you for confirming what I had was correct.